# My PHP code is not picking up the variables when using the mail function

Tags: php, forms, email

My PHP code is not picking up the variables in $message, when $message is sent to an email address using the mail function the variables are missing. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
    <?php

    $to = 'test@email.com';
    $subject = 'Booking';

    $name = $_post['name'];
    $email = $_post['email'];
    $pickup = $_post['pickup'];
    $destination = $_post['destination'];

    $message = <<<Email
    Hi,
    Please pick up $name from $pickup and drop to $destination
    Email;

    $header = $email;


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);

    echo "Message Sent";

    ?>
```

The html code is provided below, not sure why $_POST is not pulling through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form action="form.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Book your Journey</legend>
            <label for ="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
            <label for="pickup"> Pick Up Location</label>
            <input type="text" id="pickup" name="pickup">
            <label>Time:</label>
            <select>
                <option>--HR--</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
            <label>:</label>
            <select>
                <option>--MIN--</option>
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option value="am">am</option>
                <option value="pm">pm</option>
            </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <label for="destination"> Destination Postal Code</label>
            <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination">
        </fieldset>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does your email say `Hi,
    Please pick up $name from $pickup and drop to $destination` or `Hi,
    Please pick up from and drop to`?

Comment: I might be making something up right now, but I'm pretty sure it's `$_POST` and not `$_post`

Comment: Ah no, @Jhecht has figured it out.

Comment: why the line `$header = $email;` ? The header should have something like  From or Reply-To have before a mail address

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't necessarily that `$message` isn't picking up the variables. Rather, the problem is that `$name`, `$email`, etc. are all blank values.

PHP's variables are case sensitive, and `$_POST` should be all upper case.

You can do a test by outputting your `$email`, `$name`, etc. and you'll see that they're blank.

To fix it, all you need to do is capitalize `$_POST`:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pickup = $_POST['pickup'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
```

Comment: @YasserHussain Perhaps the form element name has a typo in it, or something along those lines. Can you output $_POST (eg `print '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';`), to make sure that the key (`pickup`) is being passed to your script from your form? If you don't see an obvious problem from the output of your $_POST, can you post that output here for us to take a look at? Also, I would suggest editing out your email address when posting online.

Comment: it couldn't find location using $_POST['location'], i have added the html code to the original question, to me it looks fine :|

Comment: @YasserHussain Thanks for sharing your html. I just tested it, and I was able to get a result in $_POST['pickup'] without a problem. Do you mind posting your `print_r($_POST)` result here?

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitive ...

I also recommend using:`filter_input_array();`

You can use it as follows:

```
<?php
$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);

$to      = 'test1@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Booking';

$name        = $input['name'];
$email       = $input['email'];
$pickup      = $input['pickup'];
$destination = $input['destination'];
```

You can also use it with the GET method as follows:

```
filter_input_array (INPUT_GET);
```

The use of `?>` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

post always in upper case.$_POST['variable name'] then try it.

try this after $_POST implementation not working:

```
$message = <<<EOD
    Hi,
    Please pick up {$name}from {pickup} and drop to {$destination}
    EOD;
```